# Type.InvokeMember and reference types

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm trying to use [Type.InvokeMember(String, BindingFlags, Binder, Object, array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe%28VS.96%29.aspx)[]) with the default binder.

one of the arguments to the target method in the object array is a reference type set to null. I want the method I'm invoking to instantiate the reference type so that I can continue using it. For example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class A
    {
        public void GetReferenceType(object o)
        {
            o = new object();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object o = null;
            A a = new A();
            Type t = typeof(A);
            t.InvokeMember("GetReferenceType", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, a, new object[] { o });

            if (o == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            }
            else
            {
                //do something with o;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The workaround is to give `A` a Property and to access o through that.

Is there another way to do it without changing `A`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, you need to make two changes here:

- Make your `GetReferenceType` parameter `ref`:

  ```
  public void GetReferenceType(ref object o)
  ```

  You *have* to do this because currently your method is a no-op to the outside world. You should read my [article on parameter handling in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).
- Use the value within the array after `InvokeMember`, instead of the original reference:

  ```
  A a = new A();
  Type t = typeof(A);
  object[] args = new object[] { null };
  t.InvokeMember("GetReferenceType", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                 null, a, args);
  object o = args[0];
  ```

When you create an array e.g. with `new object[] { o }` that just copies the *value* of `o` into the array - it doesn't associate that array element with the `o` variable.

A better solution would be to make `GetReferenceType` *return* the new value, however... it's rarely a good idea to use an `out` or `ref` parameter in a `void` method.

Comment: I'd rather not change A (or it's method getReferenceType) though. Any other ways?

Comment: @Matt: No. `A.GetReferenceType` is a broken method. It's a no-op. It serves no purpose. You really need to understand why that is, to avoid getting into similar problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks to your article I understand now. Before reading that I never really saw the need for passing reference types by reference!